# pause video player when navigation bar changed in flutter

Tags: flutter, lifecycle

i'm making Tiktok clone app

i'm using IndexedStack to implement this.

all good but there is one problem

I don'k know how to pause it

this is HomeScreen()

```
  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async {
    print('didChangeAppLifecycleState CALLED ✅');
    if (state != AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      _videoListController.currentPlayer.pause();
    }
  }
```

This is navigationBar code

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
      HomeScreen(), // Video is here ✅
      SearchScreen(),
      ProductScreen(),
      ProfileScreen(),
    ];

    return Scaffold(
      body: IndexedStack(index: _selectedIndex, children: _widgetOptions),
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white, boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            blurRadius: 20,
            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(.1),
          ),
        ]),

        ...
```

in HomeScreen()
didChangeAppLifecycleState is not called when change navigation index
so, player doensn't stop automatically

how can I solve this ??